# extract meaning of a word in C#

Tags: c#, synonym

I m doing a project which invoves extracting the semantics of a word. While doing some resaerch I found out it's better to get Synonyms of a word rather than trying to extract semantics.

What is the best way of doing this. I only need to get the synonym of a word.

Please help.

Comment: Did your research suggest any data structures that are commonly used for this? Did you take a look to find any C# implementations of these?  Have you written any code so far?

Comment: Well, first off, neither the C# compiler nor the CLR understand English.

Comment: apart from an english word, is synonym some library or product with which I am unfamiliar? Its a fairly complicated piece of code to write from scratch :-p

Comment: @Jodrell: Considering that the OP is talking about extracting semantics, I doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Find a thesaurus.  Pay attention to its licensing.  E.g., [Roget's Thesaurus](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/22).  There may be one that is better-suited to being parsed programmatically.
2. Parse the thesaurus.  For example, you could might store it in a `Dictionary<string,List<string>>`.
3. Look up entries as needed.  How this is done depends on what data structure you stored it in.  It's pretty easy in a `Dictionary`.

If you have trouble with a specific step in this process, feel free to ask.  Your question is a bit too open-ending for me to know exactly what part to focus on.

Comment: `class Thesaurus<T> : Dictionary<T, List<T>>`

Comment: @BoltClock: I usually prefer composition over inheritance.  I would not anticipate passing the `Thesaurus` around to functions that wanted a `Dictionary`, and in those situations where I needed to do so I would just pass around the internal `Dictionary` directly.  I consider the underlying data type of the `Thesaurus` class to be an implementation detail.  I might consider having the `Thesaurus` class implement `IDictionary`, though.